# Select box not working

Tags: selection-tools

All the Selection tools (with the exception of tweak) have suddenly stopped working in my version of Blender 4.0

When I select using the tweak, The Shade Smooth dialogue box appears. I'm able to use the select tools in edit mode without any problems.

I was wondering if there was something wrong with my Mouse/ Wacom tablet/ Computer, but a restart has made no difference, and everything is fine in older versions of Blender.

Any ideas where I should look next?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, when you say "When I select using the tweak, The Shade Smooth dialogue box appears." what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Normally, if you select an item, and (in my case) right click and choose shade smooth, or auto-smooth you get a little dialogue box open up offering various options. When I select an object with Tweak Select, this box appears as if I'd asked for a shading option. This makes me think there's something more than basic user-error at play...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the problem!

I just noticed in the right-click dialogue box a new addition to the shade auto-smooth option. It said "left click shortcut" (or words to that effect). Right-clicking on that gave me the option to "remove short-cut". Once it was removed, box select came back as normal. I don't know how I came to unintentionally create this short-cut in the first place, but it had show-stopping consequences.

Apologies to anyone wasting any time trying to figure this one out. I was wrong. It was user-error.